# jquery slider jerky in chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, safari, google-chrome, slider

Does anybody know why this slider works well in every browser except for safari and chrome?

[www.aus-media.com/dev/site_BYJ/about-bikram-yoga/postures-benefits.html](http://www.aus-media.com/dev/site_BYJ/about-bikram-yoga/postures-benefits.html)

Let me know if seeing the code will help.

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I worked it out for myself for once. I was float:left on the parent div for the slider. I removed float left... and presto it works.